# Mirror object - Rendering is not equal on both sides.. why?

Tags: rendering, texture-baking, mirror

I have a object wich I have added mirror twice.. but when I render and bake the texture, it isn't the same on both sides.. why is that?[image]

Comment: It looks like its getting flipped around the `Y` axis

Comment: How can I fix that?

Comment: Could you [post a .blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), I'm not sure how you even did that? Be sure to pack the textures

Comment: now I have post a .blend file

Comment: @HRun to post the blend file, edit your question and add the link to your file.

Comment: have found out what is wrong .. just silly me, had baked  shadows and there was something wrong when I did that.. so it was my texture that was wrong.. ;)

Comment: May you please put this in an answer so other users with the same problem can get help. Also it will get your question of my "KillTheUnansweredQuestionASAP" list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have found out what is wrong .. just silly me, had baked shadows and there was something wrong when I did that.. so it was my texture that was wrong.. ;)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I was asked to put this in as an answer, so it could be marked as answered =)

Comment: my bad :) thx for it then :)